# how to pass variables/arguments between stages in gitlab ci file?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, aws-sts

I have couple of steps/stages set up in my .gitlab-ci.yml file (shown below) . in one of the stage , i install aws cli and assume a role. is it possible to pass values i get from aws sts call to another stage in gitlab. or is it possible to have different script running in different images in the same step. so that we don't have to pass credentials to another stage? I did some research and found out few SO questions on this, for example write variables to a file and export them as artifacts , but how do i read them in my next step?

```
stage_one:
  stage: transform
  image: alpineimage
  script: 
    - apt update && apt install -y awscli
    - export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" \
$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole \
--role-session-name MySessionName \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" \
--output text))

stage_two
   stage: transform
   image: someotherimage
   script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not what you asked but all that convolution can be avoided by simply using AWS SDKs features.

E.g.

```yaml
job:
  id_token:
    TOKEN_AWS:
      aud: https://aws.com
  variables:
    AWS_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole
    AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE: $RUNNER_TEMP_PROJECT_DIR/aws-web-identity-toke-file
  before_script:
    - echo $TOKEN_AWS > $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
  script: ...
```

if you are using [OIDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html#cli-configure-role-oidc).

Otherwise, just delegate [assuming the role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#assuming-an-iam-role) to the terraform AWS provider

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also worth being listed here: if the artifact is declared in a `artifacts:reports:dotenv` section, downstream jobs will load it automatically.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job

```yaml
job1:
  variables:
     AWS_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole
  script:
    - printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" $(aws sts get-session-token --output=text --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]') > aws.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv:
        paths:
          - aws.env
        expire_in: 15 minutes

job2:
  needs: [job1]
  script:
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Concerns stay the same: secrets might be exposed as artifacts. So  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75803649/11715259 should generally be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do that convoluted thing, a strict answer to your question is

```
job1:
  variables:
     AWS_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole
  script:
    - printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" $(aws sts get-session-token --output=text --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]') > .env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env
    expire_in: 15 minutes

job2:
  needs: [job1]
  before_script:
    - export $(< .env)
  script:
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Beware this exposes secret credentials as artifacts so think twice about the thread model in your organization before opting for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to echo and export...

When read the values then can export into a vars.env and reuse, this best used for static values that not worried about exposing:

```
{
echo “VAR_NAME1=$VAR_VALUE1”
echo “VAR_NAME2=$VAR_VALUE2”
} >>${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/vars.env

artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env
```

To not expose the values then an option is probably just to rerun the AWS STS command on each step.

```
.aws_configuration:
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  
  before_script:
    - |
      aws --version
      ... set keys etc...
      aws sts get-caller-identity

job1:
  stage: stage1
  extends:
    - .aws_configuration
  script:
    - echo "do magic here"

job2:
  stage: stage2
  extends:
    - .aws_configuration
  script:
    - echo "do more magic"
```

Each job then can fetch the AWS STS user role information which means if decide need to rerun job2 you can which as pipeline builds and add more jobs don't always need to start again.

Comment: AFAIU, the question specifically needs to run the script with an image other than `amazon/aws-cli` where AWS' CLI is unavailable.